# Django-Rest-Framework AssertionError HTTPresponse Expected

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

When i do the following command over Terminal using curl

```
curl -X POST http://myuser:mypassword@myweb.com:8000/call/make-call/ -d "tutor=1&billed=1"
```

I get the following error

> AssertionError at /call/make-call/ Expected a `Response`,
>   `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the
>   view, but received a `<type 'NoneType'>`

My views.py is

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def startCall(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        serializer = startCallSerializer(data=request.DATA)

        if serializer.is_valid():

            serializer.save()

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        else:

            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

my serializer.py is

```
class startCallSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = call
        fields = ('tutor', 'billed', 'rate', 'opentok_sessionid')
```

my urls.py is

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'api.views',
    url(r'^call/make-call/$','startCall', name='startCall'),
)
```

Comment: You should use a debugger like pdb to step through your code, watch the control flow and see what is being returned by the views.

Answer (score 17):

The function does not return a `Response` object on "GET" request. That is `if request.method == 'POST'` check does not pass.

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def startCall(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = startCallSerializer(data=request.DATA)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
             return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
    # Return Response instance if request method 
    # is not POST
    return Response({'key': 'value'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
#Return this if request method is not POST
    return Response(json.dumps({'key': 'value'},default=json_util.default))
```

if you don't have an error code built in your application development.

My full code :

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def uploadFiletotheYoutubeVideo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        file_obj = request.FILES['file']#this is how Django accepts the files uploaded. 
        print('The name of the file received is ')
        print(file_obj.name)
        posteddata = request.data
        print("the posted data is ")
        print(posteddata)
        response = {"uploadFiletotheYoutubeVideo" : "uploadFiletotheYoutubeVideo"}
        return Response(json.dumps(response, default=json_util.default))
    #Return this if request method is not POST
    return Response(json.dumps({'key': 'value'},default=json_util.default))
```

Answer (score 0):

Editing the views like below should work

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def startCall(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = startCallSerializer(data=request.data)
    data={}
    if serializer.is_valid():
        datas = serializer.save()
        data['tutor']=datas.tutor
        data['billed']=datas.billed
        data['rate']=datas.rate


    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was resolved by reordering the methods in api_view()

Original Code:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def startCall(request):
```

Solution 1 Updated Code:

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
def startCall(request):
```

Or else remove other methods if not in use

Solution 2 Updated Code:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def startCall(request):
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed I had not added request.method and that was where the error was coming from

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35251454)